# Having problems changing the <dataConfiguration> section of web.config in WDP

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, asp.net-2.0, web-deployment-project

I have a web.config file that contains a section like this:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </configSections>
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="dev"/>
```

And in my web deployment projects, I have a build that replaces the dataConfiguration section, using this line:

```
dataConfiguration=webStaging.dataConfiguration.config;
```

The file itself looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="staging"></dataConfiguration>
```

For some reason when I try to build it, I get this error:

> Error 49  An error occurred creating
>   the configuration section handler for
>   dataConfiguration: Could not load file
>   or assembly
>   'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data,
>   Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.
>   (\server\websites\scancenter\web.config
>   line 22)  C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\WebDeployment\v9.0\Microsoft.WebDeployment.targets    614 9   ScanCenter_deploy

The unusual part about this is that I can replace other sections of web.config without any problem, and it's only when I include this replacement that I get an error. Any ideas?

**Update:**

I think this might be related. Our references to the enterprise library come from a UNC path, so we have refresh files that point to them.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure you are missing something. Since you are using Enterprise library, I suggest you make use of the tool provided with it to build your config file.

i. Use the tool with enterprise library to construct your config file.

ii. I am sure it will work. Now go back to your code and try to identify the mistake.

Comment: I did use the enterprise library tool to rebuild my web.config, just to make sure it wasn't different. It is different - it does not include Version, Culture, and PublicKeyToken.
I've heard that the EL tool is mistaken, but it doesn't matter, because either way the project doesn't build, unless I remove the section replacement.